# Chord Wise Load Distribution

Tags: aerodynamics

I'm looking for some guidance on how to compute the chord-wise lift distribution of the wing using Xflr5 or OpenVsp or any analytical method. This is for designing the internal structure of the wing.

I appreciate any help you can offer.

Comment: FWIW: To the question "*can I obtain the pressure distribution in the chordwise direction for a segment of the wing in XFLR5*", [this forum answer says yes](https://sourceforge.net/p/xflr5/discussion/679396/thread/a949323483/): "*switch to the Cp view (F9) in the 3d module*"